Should the tag "subconscious" be renamed to "unconscious"?
If I am not mistaken, the term "subconscious" is related to psychoanalysis and is usually avoided in academic psychology. Instead the term "unconscious" is used to describe phenomena happening without conscious awareness. 
Therefore: 
Should the tag subconscious be renamed to unconscious?

Isn't unconscious-mind a better term? Seeing "unconscious" out of context looks like it's about people who have passed out.

In principle the lack of context might lead to this misinterpretation, but I would think that, since this is a cognitive science Q&A, the context is clearly defined. I never read a psychology paper about people that had passed out. Nevertheless renaming the tag would be fine with me.

True enough, I'll Tag Wiki it though to clarify

That was my mistake, and my fault for not being actually involved in academic psychology. I listened to the source I was quoting again, and indeed I had misquoted. Eric Kandell was indeed talking about the unconscious and did not use the term subconscious.
I have updated and retagged my question; thank you for bringing this up!

Many thanks for clarifying.

That sounds reasonable to me. I think "subconscious" has only been used on one question. So it's pretty simple to change that.

Yes, only one so far, but I was about to add "unconscious" to two other questions and noted the existence of the "subconscious" tag.
